# Javascript using nested for and splice

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I'm trying too look for points in a polygon.

So I have an array with point-objects and an array with polygon-objects.

I want to iterate over my points-array and than iterate over the polygon-array and look if the point is in that array. If the point is in the array I want to remove the point from the points-array because one point can only be in one polygon.

So I tried to use this function:

```
function pointsInPolygons(features, points) {
    var pointCopy = $.extend(true, [], points.features);
    for (var i = 0; i < pointCopy.length; i++) {
        var point = pointCopy[i];
        for (var j = 0; j < features.features.length; j++) {
            var feature = features.features[j];
            if (isPoly(feature) && gju.pointInPolygon(point.geometry, feature.geometry)) {
                feature.properties.ratings.push(point.properties.rating);
                pointCopy.splice(i, 1);
                i--;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But after going through the inner for, the function is leaving. I tried the same without splice and decreasing i. But it is still the same behavior.

So the question is how can I get into the outer for again?

Comment: At the point where you've just done the splice, do you want to `break` to jump out of the inner loop and continue with the next iteration of the outer loop?

Comment: yes that's what I want

Comment: So...I'm saying to literally add `break;` immediately after the `i--;` statement (inside the `if` block).

Comment: I tried a lot now. It works with and without the break. But my error was at another place. The second object of my testdata was wrong. So this function couldn't work. Thanks for your hints.

Comment: Iterate backwards in the outerloop: `for (var i=pointCopy.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)`, avoids the use of `i--` in the inner loop.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you don't have to remove the item from the array, your current for loop against `points` will only iterate through once. Here's a flatten approach to what you're doing.

```
function pointsInPolygons(features, points){
  let pointsCopy = points.features.slice();
  let check = (point,feature) => isPoly(feature) && gju.pointInPolygon(point.geometry, feature.geometry);
  let isInPolygon = point => features.find(check.bind(null, point));

  pointsCopy.forEach(point => {
    let feature = isInPolygon(point);
    if (!!feature) {
      feature.properties.ratings.push(point.properties.rating);
    }
  });
}
```